# Magento 2 update price with SQL command

Tags: magento2, php, price, sql

I want to update products price with SQL. I already tried with my code below, but nothing happened. Is there something wrong on my code?

Block :

```
public function changePriceSql($csv){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal'); //gives table name with prefix
    for ($i=0; $i < count($csv); $i++) { 
        //Select Data from table
        $sql = "Update value FROM " . $tableName . "Set value =" .$csv[$i][1]. "WHERE value_id =" . $csv[$i][0];
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

phtml :

```
$check = $this->changePriceSql($csv3);
```

`$csv3` contain data from csv file : id, price, qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I feel the way of method you are using is totally wrong. You should never user sql queries directly and for sure you should not implement the same in your block instead create a model.

Moreover the `catalog_product_entity_decimal` will have plenty of values stored (i.e) (price, special price, etc).

```
$sql = "Update value FROM " . $tableName . "set value =" .$csv[$i][1]. "WHERE attribute_id = 77 AND value_id = $csv[$i][0];
```

Here 77 in where clause is the attribute ID of price. Also you should get this attribute ID by calling the attribute Model and get its ID dynamically as this differ instance to instance.